# "Calls to the web service will fail unless the Silverlight project is hosted in and launched from the same web project"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight, wcf-data-services

I have Downloaded demo project  from [here](http://www.timecockpit.com/en/blogs/10-09-10/time_cockpit_at_NRWConf.aspx.)

I tried to run Silverlight project `SkiResult.ThinClient`  from the  “`Solution  Explorer`”  I have configured the database nicely as `SkiResult.FullClient` a **WPF Project**   works fine and display data.
But whenever **I have tried to run Silverlight project** in my Solution Explorer it shows me following error message.

[image]

I have **googled** so much I have also found one solution that set  **`xyz.WEB project`** as  a **Start Up Project** but as u can see from below screenshot of my **Solution Explorer** there is no  **`xyz.WEB project`**  in solution.

[image]

**Thank you so much.....**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `SkiResult.DataService` project to be the startup project.  This looks very much a web project created to host a Silverlight application because:

- it has a Web.config file (so it is clearly a web project)
- it has a `Silverlight.js` file (some utility JavaScript used with Silverlight),
- it has some autogenerated test pages,
- it has a ClientBin folder, which is typically where the compiled Silverlight application will be copied to.

When you create a Silverlight project, Visual Studio offers to create a web application project to host the Silverlight application for you.  (You don't have to create a web application - VS can generate a test webpage during the build process and use that instead.)  If your Silverlight project is called `Xyz`, then this web application will be called `Xyz.Web`.  However, with the solution you're dealing with above, it seems this project has been renamed from the default.

Comment: i have tried but when i set `SkiResult.DataService` **Set as a Start Up** it shows me error message **Unable to attach. A debugger is already attached.** thank you so much

Comment: @Pritesh: I've not seen that message myself starting up Silverlight applications, so I can only really guess at what could cause that message.  Are you running two instances of Visual Studio, perhaps?  Are there any `WebDev_WebServer.EXE` (ASP.NET dev server) processes running?  Ensure only one VS is running, kill off all `WebDev_WebServer.EXE` processes and try again.

Comment: ya exactly .......i have close all the instances and now project Run nicely.....thank you so much........